# cycling through a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjKgF/5/)

Use the arrow keys to cycle trough the div list. As you can see there is a gap after ''Mark'' and above ''Luca''. In other words; at some point non of the divs has a blue background. My question: How can I cycle trough the divs without the gap?

(Focus the input first)

Comment: I don't see any gap in FF4, it appears to be working fine.

Comment: Oh, you mean after you run out from the bottom, before you cycle back?

Comment: Yep that is what I mean. It conflicts with my script.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Im going to go for solution by Amadan because of the ''slight modification''. I like simple things:) But I think all of the answers are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only a slight modification of your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf2mR/

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go for a solution using the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator) (`%`) to reset the selection index to 0 when it goes less than that or greater than the number of elements:

```
var curr = $('#display').find('.current');    
    ind = curr.index(),
    all = curr.parent().children(),
    adj = e.keyCode == 40 ? 1 : -1;

if (!curr.length)
    all = $("#display").children(), ind = e.keyCode == 40 ? -1 : 0;

$(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');    
all.eq((ind + adj) % all.length).attr('class', 'display_box current');
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sjKgF/50/**

(Edit: fixed edge case where no item is initially highlighted because of reset by mouseover).
(Edit 2: refactored.  You can see that working with modulus allows us to get rid of a few if statements and shorten the code).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `if(curr.length)` will be true when you're on the last one (going down), thus `curr.next()` doesn't exist (when going down). The same is true when you are on the first element going up.
so you want to change your if statements to be like this

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) 
    {    
        $(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');        
        if(curr.length && $(curr).next().length > 0)
        {
            $(curr).next().attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }
        else{
            $('#display div:first-child').attr('class', 'display_box current');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check for the edge cases

```
   $('#search').keyup(
    function (e){
        var curr = $('#display').find('.current');
        if (e.keyCode == 40) 
        {                                      
            if(curr.length && $(curr).next().length > 0)
            {
                    $(curr).removeClass('current');
                    $(curr).next().addClass('current');
            }
            else{
                $('#display div:first-child').addClass('current');
            }                    
        }
        if(e.keyCode==38)
        {                                        
            if(curr.length && $(curr).prev().length > 0)
            {                            
                    $(curr).removeClass('current');
                    $(curr).prev().addClass('current');
            }
            else{
                $('#display div:last-child').addClass('current');
            }            
        }
    }        
    )
```